# Retrieve the balance for a Stripe Connect connected account?

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

How can the balance on a connected account be retrieved? (e.g. a connected account is like the 'host' in the Airbnb example).

I checked the [balances](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance) docs, and hoped there'd be something like:

```rb
stripe_account = 'acct_lsdkjflsdkjflkj'
Stripe::Balance.retrieve(stripe_account)
```

but the docs only show how to get the balance for the ***platform***'s account, rather than that of a connected account.

I also tried `Stripe::Account.retrieve('acct_lsdkjflsdkjflkj')` but that returns info about the account but the not balance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to use the Stripe-Account header [0] to make API requests for connected accounts.

Example

```
$balance = Stripe::Balance.retrieve({stripe_account: 'acct_...'})
```

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication

Comment: No idea why it's often so hard to find this simple stuff in their docs. Thank you